# Spring AuthenticationPrincipal giving null parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to get logged in user by AuthenticationPrincipal.

```
@RequestMapping("/cart")
public String showCart(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User principal){
    int id = principal.getId();
```

According to docummentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal

I should add the AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver, so did I.

The problem is principal is actually a null.

**Edit:**

By using:

```
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username =  ((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
```

I can get to the user I want to fetch, but since I need an ID of given user (which is not originally stored in default User), I need to get it from database (which is less effective as I should already have that ID stored somewhere)